# Can't figure out how to make Gradle find/load my Main class

Tags: java, gradle, bots, discord

I can't seem to get Gradle to see my build path and find my main class.

I have looked all over for solutions (including on here, tried changing the SetSource and rearranging where everything was filewise).

This is my gradle.build file:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'

sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
mainClassName = 'botstuff.Main'

version '1.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
   compile 'net.dv8tion:JDA:3.8.1_456'

   compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-nop.jar', version: '1.7.25'
}

compileJava.options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
```

My file path for relevant files is:

src (set to be the default in the gradle sourceSets.main)

--botstuff

--------main

I only seemed to have gotten a message of Error: `Could not find or load main class botstuff.Main` in the Eclipse console since adding in the SLF4J (which fixed it not running previous for lack of a logger).

Comment: Your main class is called 'Main.java' and is located in src/botstuff ?

Comment: Yes, 'botstuff' is the package that 'Main.java' is located in